# Finding out the value of a particular column of the current row of a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row

We have a DataGridView with 3 columns:
InvoicedOn, PaidOn and Amount

On the MouseDown event is this line of code which needs to be fixed:

```
MsgBox(DataGridViewPayments.Item("Amount", DataGridViewPayments.CurrentRow.Index), "")
```

We are trying to find out what the value in the Amount column of the curent row.

We also get this error message:

```
Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Can you tell me how to fix the MsgBox so it will show the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `DataGridViewPayments.Item("Amount", DataGridViewPayments.CurrentRow.Index)` will get the **DataGridViewCell** at intersection of column named "Amount" (supposing it exists) with the current row index (supposing the CurrentRow is not Nothing).

To get the value of that cell you need to reference the property of the DataGridViewCell named `Value`

```
DataGridViewPayments.Item("Amount", DataGridViewPayments.CurrentRow.Index).Value
```

The `Amount` column suggest that a numeric value is present, but, keep in mind, if the current cell is empty or null, you probably get an exception. In that case would be preferable to do:

```
object o = DataGridViewPayments.Item("Amount", DataGridViewPayments.CurrentRow.Index).Value
if o Is Nothing OrElse o.ToString = "" then 
  MsgBox("The cell is empty or null", "Message Title")
else
  MsgBox("The cell value is " + o.ToString, "Message Title")
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful code and quick reply. I will use that.

Answer (score 1):

Use column index instead of column name

```
MsgBox(DataGridViewPayments.Item(2, DataGridViewPayments.CurrentRow.Index)).value, "")
```